# Simple currency observer

Tags: api, web

I am trying to use the cryptsy.com's API to get the current price of doge. This is my code.

```
package main;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import main.Cryptsy.CryptsyException;
import main.Cryptsy.PublicMarket;


public class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws CryptsyException, InterruptedException{

        Cryptsy cryptsy = new Cryptsy();

        while(true){
            PublicMarket[] markets = cryptsy.getPublicMarketData();
            for(PublicMarket market : markets) {
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
                if(market.label.equals("DOGE/BTC"))
                    System.out.println(new Date() + "   " + market.label + "   " + df.format(market.lasttradeprice));
            }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the price get updated too rear (30 mins or something) and only if I restart my program. Anyone to know how to get the current price? Also there is connection errors sometimes.

Comment: Well, [the API you seem to have borrowed](https://github.com/abwaters/cryptsy-api/blob/master/src/com/abwaters/cryptsy/Cryptsy.java) will just call the service as defined on the [Cryptsy page](https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/api) so it would be interesting to know what happens if you call the API manually in your browser - do the data get updated faster?  Also, as you just seem interested in 1 label retrieving them all and throwing out all but 1 is a bit heavy handed, there is a call that will just retrieve 1 market.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the connection problems are normal with the Cryptsy API. It's slow and often disconnects without an answer. They are overcrowded like all the times.

There is a new API location that should be faster and solve the connection issies, here:

http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2

And also, if you are only interested in one single currency, you can get the market data of only that currency. The whole Answer from Cryptsy for all Currencies is like 300k, so you would waste bandwith, if you poll that every minute or so.

For only one currency it will be like:

http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid={MARKET ID}

Where the market ID can be gathered inside the answer of the first URL. But you just need the int ID of the market once, from then on you can always use the direct call..

Every Detail is BTW available here:

https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/api